# Change edmx designer, manually change the multiplicity of the "1" side of the association so it becomes 1-n

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm using database first approach and I'm getting this error

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   Error 113: Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in
>   Role 'UserInformation' in relationship 'FK_Tokens_UserInformation'.
>   Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable,
>   multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'. DataModel
>   F:\kode\TheWork\TheWork2\TheWork\DataModel\Model1.edmx 134

***Some one said I can manually change  in the edmx designer, manually change the multiplicity of the "1" side of the association so it becomes 1-n***

*But How I tried to do that but there is no option available*

Update
[image]

Comment: If I recall correctly, you need to open the edmx file, select the association - the dashed line - between the entities and hit F4 and then in properties you should see Multiplicity for both ends.

Comment: @KarelTamayo Please see the Image and tell me which one to select as both seem 1 to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   Error 113: Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in
>   Role 'UserInformation' in relationship 'FK_Tokens_UserInformation'.
>   Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable,
>   multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'. DataModel
>   F:\kode\TheWork\TheWork2\TheWork\DataModel\Model1.edmx 134

As per the error message you should choose the second option in the image you provide. That will set the multiplicity for the relation to 1 (strict).

There is an important difference here between both options. In the first case, you have 0..1 (Zero or One) and that only will be possible to manage if your foreign key field on the dependent entity is of a nullable type.

Lets say you have:

```
public class UserInformation
{
    public ICollection<Token> Tokens {get;set;}
}

public class Token
{
    public int UserInformationId {get;set;}

    public UserInformation UserInfo {get;set;}
}
```

As you can see, there is no way with this design to handle the case for when you don't have any `UserInfo` linked to a given `Token`, because the field `UserInformationId` is of type int, hence it'll always have an acceptable value. It turns out to be 0 by default, but that's still a valid value for a FK.

So, EF is letting you know that due to the properties in the model you need to set the multiplicity to strict 1. If you want to be able to represent the relation as 0..1 the you need to allow the FK to be `Nullable<int>` for the case when no `UserInformation` is present.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay as you said I selected the second option and Now I get this error 
its the same but now says 0..1----------------------
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Running transformation: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'UserInformation' in relationship 'FK_Tokens_UserInformation'. Because all the properties in the Dependent Role are nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '0..1'. DataModel F:\kode\TheWork\TheWork2\TheWork\DataModel\Model1.edmx 134

Comment: And same is with The Token table and there is another error with just a bit different yet the same as ---------------
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Running transformation: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Tokens' in relationship 'FK_Tokens_UserInformation'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be *. DataModel F:\kode\TheWork\TheWork2\TheWork\DataModel\Model1.edmx 134

Comment: Please double check you changed the correct End of the relation.

Comment: Just to be sure, in your model UserInformation has a collection of Tokens right? If that's the case, then the multiplicity for UserInformation should be 1 and the multiplicity for Tokens should be set to *

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fwva02 Please see the Screen shot link is available. I've changed only one. not the other

Comment: Yes same error also now it says Entities and other created classes are also missing. http://prntscr.com/fwvc12

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149417/discussion-between-karel-tamayo-and-dummy).

Comment: Thanks mate after making some other code changes I was able to solve this and project is running now, I;ll mark this as answer